# Create 1 x n pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way to create a 1 x n data frame using pandas? It appears that pandas fills dataframes by column, whereas it would be easier to create dataframes by row with my data.

For example, I currently use pd.DataFrame(range(10)).transpose() to create a one row dataframe, but I'm worried that calling the transpose method is somewhat slowing down my code as I'm working with more data.

Comment: Why do you want to do this, iteratively growing the df is non-performant row or column-wise. anyway you can do `pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(1,10))` to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is to:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([range(10)])
```

#### Explanation

`range(10)` is inherently 1 dimensional (, 10).  It's a mistake to think it is (1, 10).  To fix this you specify it as `[range(10)]`.  This is now (1, 10)

#### Edit to add EdChum's answer and for posterity.

And because @EdChum enjoys answering questions in comments for the time being.  Upvote his comment if you like this answer.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(1, 10))
```

### I tested these all out for speed.

#### OP's solution

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(range(10)).transpose() 

1000 loops, best of 3: 223 µs per loop
```

#### My solution

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame([np.arange(10)])

1000 loops, best of 3: 783 µs per loop
```

#### EdChum's solution

```
%%timeit
pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(1, 10))

10000 loops, best of 3: 86.4 µs per loop
```

EdChum's is clearly more efficient.